# How to traversal or return the signalName of all elements of a bundle?

Tags: scala, bundle, chisel

Could you enlight me how to traversal the signalName of a bundle?
like

```
class test extends Bundle {
  val io = IO(new Bundle{
    val a = Input(Bool())
    val b = Input(Bool())
  })
  for ( signame <- io.elements) {
    printf("%s \n",signame)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The type of [elements](https://chisel.eecs.berkeley.edu/api/index.html#chisel3.core.Bundle@elements:scala.collection.immutable.ListMap[String,chisel3.core.Data]) is `ListMap[String, Data]`, so the correct way to iterate on the elements of a Bundle is:

```
for ((name, data) <- io.elements) {
  printf(s"$name -> %d\n", data)
}
```

Comment: Could you enlight me what I did wrong to the follwoing code?